# How to display results of an online quiz (no java/sql, pure php)?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I started with a comma delimited text file **data.txt**

> What is a panda?,An animal,A plant,A family member,A teacher
>  What is a
>   rubix cube?,A puzzle,A maze,A box,A museum
>  HTML is...,Main markup
>   language for web pages,Cross-site Security,Cleverly Structured
>   Scripting,eXtremely Safe and Secure
>  PHP is...,General-purpose
>   server-side scripting language,Cross-site Security,Processing
>   Hypertext Products,Process HTML Prettily

I loaded my questions from the text file and my **main.php** looks like this

```
<h2>MasterQuiz Online</h2>
<p>Where would you like to go?</p>

<ul>
    <li><a href='question.php'>Take quiz</a></li>
    <li><a href='module.php'>Admin Module</a></li>
</ul>

<?php
//text file
$file = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
//array setup
$array = array();
while ($line = fgetcsv($file)) {
   $array[] = $line;
}

fclose($file);

session_start();
$_SESSION["questions_array"]=$array;

//display var and index
var_dump($array);

?>
```

While this is what my **question.php** looks like

```
<h2>Online Quiz</h2>

<form action="answer.php" method="post">

<?php

session_start();
if(sizeof($_SESSION['questions_array']) > 0 )
{
    // Get the next question off of the quiz in session
    $data = array_shift($_SESSION["questions_array"]);

    echo '<p>'.array_shift($data).'</p>'; // next question
    //shuffle($data); //shuffle choices, toggle if needed

    foreach ($data as $a => $answer){ //answers
        echo 
             '<input type="radio" name="question-'.$data.'" id="question-'.$data.'"'.
             'value="'.$a.'"/>'.
             '<label for="question-'.$data.'">'.$answer.'</label>'.
             '<br>';
             }  
}
else{
  header('location:result.php'); //questions array is empty, go to results page
}
?>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Basically I need two result pages.

One is for every time the `submit` button is hit, the user is directed to another page (**answer.php**) where it displays whether the user got the correct answer or not. A continue button is also displayed so that the user may move on to the next question.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

> ### Question Results
>
> **CORRECT / INCORRECT** //depends if user got the correct answer or not
>
> **Correct Answer:** //insert correct answer 
>   **Your Answer:** //insert user selected answer
>
> (continue link)

So far, this is what my **answer.php** looks like

```
<h2>Question Results</h2>

<?php

session_start();
$array=$_SESSION["questions_array"];

//insert whether correct or incorrect here

echo "Your answer:<br>";
echo "Correct answer:".$array[0][1];

?>
<br><br>
<a href="question.php">Continue</a>
```

But it doesn't work. And I'm completely stuck as to why. The `$array[0][1]` gave me something different (the wrong array value I'm looking for) as to what it gives me on other pages (the value I'm looking for).

If you guys have any suggestions on how I can make my codes better and working, I'd appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

And the second one (I'm so sorry if this is getting long but I don't want to do separate posts on the same idea)

I need to make a results page (**result.php**) where the overall result is displayed once user completes the quiz.

*example output:*

[image]

Truthfully, I'm confused on how to do that as this is my first time doing something like this.

My **result.php**

```
<h2>Total Results</h2>

<?php

//table of results
echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr><th>Question</th><th>Your answer</th><th>Correct answer</th><th>Points</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Question#1</td><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Question#2</td><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Question#3</td><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Question#4</td><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Question#5</td><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
  <tr><th>Total Points</th></tr>
  </table>";

?>
<br>
<a href="p05_main.php">Back to homepage</a>
```

The values in the table are just there temporarily as it makes me think better. I'm sorry if it confuses anyone!

Once again, help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What about using the PHP fwrite() function to write the quiz data to file(s), then recalling the data on your results.php page(s) with the fopen() and/or related functions: feof(), fgets/fgetcsv(), etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to use fwrite() as I've never used it before but I'll look into it and try it out! (I might take a while) Thanks for the suggestion =]

Comment: You're welcome.  I personally haven't used it yet either as I write to MySQL, but I've read about fwrite() and since you specifically excluded SQL, etc. in favor of PHP only, fwrite() seemed like a possibility.  Also, apparently file_put_contents() is an alternative to fwrite().